# Postgres: order of index

Tags: postgresql

Does order of index (ASC or DESC) impacts the `SELECT` with `ORDER BY` in opposite direction?

For example, suppose we have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Comments"
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Comments_id_seq"'::regclass),
    child_count integer DEFAULT 0,
    comment text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT "Comments_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

And index on `child_count` column:

```
CREATE INDEX child_count
ON public."Comments" USING btree
(child_count)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

(I.e., in `ASC` order by default.)

Than we run a statement:

```
SELECT id, child_count, comment
FROM public."Comments"
ORDER BY child_count DESC
OFFSET 0
LIMIT 100
```

Do we need to invert index direction?

Comment: Check the execution plan using `explain (analyze)`

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-ordering.html) "*The index can also be scanned backward, producing output satisfying ORDER BY x DESC*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Plan is identical, does this mean that order of index have no sense?

Comment: Not for this specific situation, but do read the description in the manual (the link from my comment). There are situations where specifying an order helps - e.g. for multi-column indexes

Answer (score -1):

You can adjust the ordering of a by including the options ASC, DESC, NULLS FIRST, and/or NULLS LAST when creating the index; for example:

```
CREATE INDEX test2_info_nulls_low ON test2 (info NULLS FIRST);
CREATE INDEX test3_desc_index ON test3 (id DESC NULLS LAST);
```

via https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-ordering.html

Comment: Thanks! But question is: does the ordering have any sense? Does it affects the speed of selection?